# Sine wave equation for World of Warcraft add-on

Tags: math, lua, world-of-warcraft

I am creating an add-on for World of Warcraft.

I have this:

```
if edirection == "moon" then sffem = 105*math.sin(math.pi - math.asin(cpower/105) + math.pi/20 * sfcasttime) end
```

This is working fine, but I need to put cutoff points at 100 and -100.

This is because my character's energy is based on a sine wave starting at 0 going down to -100 staying there for a few seconds coming back up to 0 going up to 100 and staying for a few seconds and returning to 0.

This works because the sine wave is for 105, -105 energy but there is a max and min player energy of 100.

I tried:

```
if edirection == "moon" then sffem = (MAX(-100;MIN(100;105*math.sin(math.pi - math.asin(cpower/105) + math.pi/20 * sfcasttime)))) end
```

This just gives an error.

How can I do this?

Comment: `math.max(-100, math.min(100,...))`

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to do this all in one line.  For example, after the line

```
if edirection == "moon" then sffem = 105*math.sin(math.pi - math.asin(cpower/105) + math.pi/20 * sfcasttime) end
```

do something like

```
if sffem >= 100 then sffem = 100 end
if sffem <= -100 then sffem = -100 end
```

(Thank you to Henrik Ilgen for syntax help)

Comment: @Ricky, if this was useful, you can click the checkmark next to it to accept this as the canonical answer, which will indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: Your code is almost syntactically correct, you're just missing an `end` after each of the two lines ;)

Comment: Thanks Henrik,  I've made those adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Your second line of code is using a semicolons instead of a commas to separate the arguments to `MAX` and `MIN`.

Your code after that change and using `math.min` and `math.max`:

```
if edirection == "moon" then sffem = math.max(-100,math.min(100,105*math.sin(math.pi - math.asin(cpower/105) + math.pi/20 * sfcasttime))) end
```

You might find it useful to make a clamping helper function:

```
function clamp(value, min, max)
  return math.max(min, math.min(max, value))
end
```

In which case your code becomes this:

```
if edirection == "moon" then sffem = clamp(105*math.sin(math.pi - math.asin(cpower/105) + math.pi/20 * sfcasttime), -100, 100) end
```